# Intent Виджет Google PlaceAutocomplete сразу закрывается после открытия

Tags: android, xamarin, google-maps, android-intent, google-places-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вызываю PlaceAutocomplete через клик по `ImageView`

```
//....
  Buttest = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageSertch);
            Buttest.Click += PlaceButonClic;
}

private void PlaceButonClic(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.ModeOverlay).Build(this);
                StartActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}



 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode==1)
                    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                    {
                            var place = Android.Gms.Location.Places.UI.PlaceAutocomplete.GetPlace(this, data);
                    DistanceText.Text = place.NameFormatted.ToString();
                    }
        }
```

Но после открытие сразу закрывается

в манифесте ключ `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDdrdvoOfj-ZcLdZ-*****************" />`

Подозреваю что проблема в ключе, но до сих пор не нашел информации

Как я могу исправить моментальное закрытие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Летом 2019 года система была обновлена и теперь нужно использовать

> Xamarin.Google.Android.Places
>
> Xamarin.Android.Volley

```
 if (!PlacesApi.IsInitialized)
            {
                PlacesApi.Initialize(this, "Api код");
            }



Buttest.Click  += delegate
            {
                List<Place.Field> Fields = new List<Place.Field>();
                Fields.Add(Place.Field.Id);
                Fields.Add(Place.Field.Name);
                Fields.Add(Place.Field.LatLng);
                Fields.Add(Place.Field.Address); 
       
                string cantriuser = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Country);
              
                var bount = RectangularBounds.NewInstance( new LatLng(MyLatitude - 2, MyLongitude - 2),new LatLng(MyLatitude + 2, MyLongitude + 2));

                var intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.Overlay, Fields)/*.SetCountry(cantriuser)*/;
                intent.SetLocationRestriction(bount);//Ограничение територии выдачи 
               
                StartActivityForResult(intent.Build(this), 1);
            };
```